Proving a certain kernel is Lipschitz
Let $k: [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous (w.r.t. product topology) and symmetric (i.e. $k(s, t) = k(t, s)$). Suppose I know the following inequality:
$$\int_0^1 |k(s, t) - k(s, r)| ds \leq |t-r| \quad \forall t, r \in [0, 1]$$
Does this imply that $k(s, \cdot)$ is Lipschitz for all $s$? How about most $s$?
Intuitively, I feel that since $k$ is bounded (continuous on compact domain), the integrand can never take value of more than $O(1)$ anywhere. If $|t-r| = o(1)$, then then only way for this to integrate to something $o(1)$ is if there are only $o(1)$-many $s$'s for which Lipschitzness fails. It feels like this should let me show that the set of $s$ for which $k(s, \cdot)$ is not Lipschitz has measure 0, from which a density argument and continuity lets me conclude? I haven't been able to make it work, but I also haven't come up with a good counterexample. I would appreciate any help :). Thank you for your time, and have a lovely weekend.
